# jump into new line after enter click inside TextBox with multi line

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `Textbox` with `MultiLine` enabled, in my application this `Textbox` controller used to insert some text.
All I want to do is to jump to a new line if the user clicks enter.

All I have tried is to find the write command inside my controller `Enter event`:

```
private void tbc_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: tbc is TextBox Controller? 
What is it? A usercontrol?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "This" + Environment.NewLine + "A" + Environment.NewLine + "Multiline" + Environment.NewLine + "Textbox.";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
```